# Append a <p> tag to an <li> and import 1st paragraph of a url into there? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've figured out how to display the first paragraph of a url onto my page by using:

```
$(".divclass").load("myurl.com .p1");
```

however my structure looks as follows:

```
<ul> <li><a>TITLE</a></li> <li><a>TITLE</a></li> <li><a>TITLE</a></li> </ul>
```

I need to grab the dynamic URL for each of those a tags and append a p tag under the `<a>` tag and in there import the first paragraph of the url...
I'm kinda confused.. any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused too, could we see a bit more of your HTML? Where is the .p1 class?

Comment: if u mean this `$('ul li a').each(function(){ $(this).load($(this).attr('href') + ' .p1') });`, it is bad idea to put ajax call into foreach

Comment: The .p1 class is just a div I surrounded the first paragraph of the page I want to import in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, your jQuery will look like this:

```
$("ul li").append("<p>your url </p>");
```

Use this example if you wanna put the same url on each li tag

Otherwise, if you have one url for each one, I recommend you to put an ID on your li tag.. It would look like this

```
<li id="firsturl"><a>TITLE</a></li>
```

For dynamic url, you have to put an ID to your input HTML form, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="dynamicurl" name="url">
```

Then, in your jquery code you'll just reference the html as it follows:

First, you gotta get the url

```
  var dynURL = $("#dynamicurl").val()
  $("#firsturl").append("<p>"+dynURL+"</p>");
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes thank you!  The only problem with this one is the url I will be using will be dynamic as people add content. So I need a way to extract the url in the a tag and use that to pull in the first paragraph

Comment: I can help you that but I'm gonna need more information. Where this url come from? the user input it on the page? you build up on your jquery code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide more information. So I'm building this in a CMS and this is for a 'recent news' section on the homepage. When a user creates a new article, the title gets pushed to the homepage and it links to that specific article. That's why I don't know the url because it's all dynamic

Comment: I suppose there is gonna be an input form that your user inserts the url. Something like this <input type="text"> am I right? If yes, all you have to do is put an ID into your input form and get the url before your append your <p> tag. I will edit my previous answer so you can see.